# The [android] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag? The majority of the questions with the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag should all go on Android Stack Exchange. I think that the tag should be removed and perhaps some more specific tags about Android added.

Comment: There are lots of good reasons to get rid of the Android tag. It being off-topic is not one of them.

Comment: Better ask to burninate PHP first :P

Comment: You sure you looked at questions in the tag and at questions at Android Enthusiasts, and believed that these two sites duplicated purpose?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag is for *programming* questions about Android. The "What topics can I ask about here?" page in Help Center on Android Stack Exchange says:

> Development/programming questions are not covered on this site. You can visit our sister site, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), instead.